# Replace exact matching string in xml string using java

Tags: java, xml

I read many articles about the regex to replace the string in xml value. In many articles most of the peoples accepted answers for

```
str=str.replaceAll("\\b2017\\b", "****");
```

But this is not working as expected and replacing 2017 in other place also. below is my example.

```
public class StringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str=
                "<OTA_InsuranceBookRQ xmlns=\"http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05\" Version=\"2.001\">                        "+
                        "  <POS>                        "+
                        "    <Source>                       "+
                        "      <TPA_Extensions>                     "+
                        "        <ProductCode>101468</ProductCode>                      "+
                        "        <PurchaseDate>2017-08-21</PurchaseDate>                        "+
                        "        <TransactionType>PURCHASE</TransactionType>                        "+
                        "        <SubmissionType>MerchantXMLPurchase</SubmissionType>                       "+
                        "      </TPA_Extensions>                        "+
                        "    </Source>                      "+
                        "  </POS>                       "+
                        "  <PlanForBookRQ PlanID=\"245235\">                        "+
                        "    <InsCoverageDetail>                        "+
                        "      <CoveredTrips>                       "+
                        "        <CoveredTrip DepositDate=\"2017-08-11T00:00:00.000Z\" End=\"2017-09-03\" FinalPayDate=\"2017-08-14T00:00:00.000Z\" Start=\"2017-09-02\">                       "+
                        "          <Destinations>                       "+
                        "            <Destination>                      "+
                        "              <StateProv/>                     "+
                        "              <CountryName>Germany</CountryName>                       "+
                        "            </Destination>                     "+
                        "          </Destinations>                      "+
                        "          <Operators>                      "+
                        "            <Operator CompanyShortName=\"Delta\" TravelSector=\"Airline\"/>                        "+
                        "            <Operator CompanyShortName=\"Carnival\" TravelSector=\"CruiseLine\"/>                      "+
                        "          </Operators>                     "+
                        "        </CoveredTrip>                     "+
                        "      </CoveredTrips>                      "+
                        "    </InsCoverageDetail>                       "+
                        "    <InsuranceCustomer>                        "+
                        "      <PaymentForm CostCenterID=\"ONLINE\" GuaranteeID=\"243356\" RPH=\"\" Remark=\"customerconfirmation@email.com\">                      "+
                        "        <PaymentCard ExpireDate=\"2017\">                      "+
                        "          <CardType Code=\"VISA\"/>                        "+
                        "          <CardHolderName>Test Booking</CardHolderName>                        "+
                        "          <Telephone PhoneNumber=\"1234567890\"/>                      "+
                        "          <Email>errorreporting@email.com</Email>                      "+
                        "          <CardNumber EncryptedValue=\"4111111111111111\"/>                        "+
                        "          <SeriesCode EncryptedValue=\"Agent who sold policy\"/>                       "+
                        "        </PaymentCard>                     "+
                        "      </PaymentForm>                       "+
                        "    </InsuranceCustomer>                       "+
                        "  </PlanForBookRQ>                     "+
                        "</OTA_InsuranceBookRQ>";
                   str=str.replaceAll("\\b2017\\b", "****");
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

when i ran this program expected result is `<PaymentCard ExpireDate="2017">` should replace with `<PaymentCard ExpireDate="****">` but along with that it also replacing 2017 value in `<PurchaseDate>2017-08-21</PurchaseDate>`     as `<PurchaseDate>****-08-21</PurchaseDate>` which is not acceptable in my case.

i tried with below regex also but no luck.

```
str=str.replaceAll("(?<!\\S)2017(?!\\S)", "****");
```

please do not mark and close this as duplicate since no answers are working as expected.

Comment: it will always be safer to use xml tools (dom/xpath, etc) to convert xml data. regex and xml have a rocky relationship. Especially given this is credit card info, i wouldn't use hacks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to replace "2017" in quotes, just do so explicitly:

```
str = str.replace("\"2017\"", "\"****\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
str=str.replaceAll("(2017(?!-))", "****");
```